# Continue running SQL procedure when SQL Developer is Closed

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there any way to execute a procedure in SQL Developer and have the procedure continue to run even in SQL Developer is closed?

Comment: as if you mean dbms_scheduler.

Comment: what are your actual requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here's an Oracle doc that will guide you through defining a scheduler job. You can use this method (or `DBMS_SCHEDULER`, or `OEM`) to schedule a job that will execute a procedure without needing to maintain database connectivity.

Would recommend reading the entire doc, but you can skip ahead to "**Schedule SQL Scripts Using SQL Developer**" to view the relevant info.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/sql-developer-17.2/DMRIG/generating-deploying-sql-scripts.htm#DMRIG260